# Windows Workflow Foundation in modular application

Tags: frameworks, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, modularity

I have a question about WWF, I'm working on a webbased ERP project which is a modular application ofcourse.
I'm looking for a way to create an engine for wokflows in the framwrok so modules can rely on it and based on this engine create their workflows.As I see there should be 3 kind of workflows (Human for confirmation of info among the organization, Business for handling business flows such as calculating personnel income based on the different factors and UI workflow for handling chain of usercontrols based on a cartable (dashboard) )
I need some help on handling this and if there is any problem in my insight I wonder to be informed.

Answer (score 1):

This is extremely broad and without more context hard to answer.

WorkFlow can be used in conjunction with e.g. SharePoint to take care of the Human part of a workflow such as creating a document or marking it as OK.

WF can be deployed as a service and supports the interaction with other (web)services to support modularity.

Comment: What you want to know? I can tell you any detail you need.Actually I'm looking for an start point or a best practice.